# Rel.to deprecated in Django 2.0

Tags: django

I am trying to upgrade the django-accounting (https://github.com/dulacp/django-accounting) to the last version of django as I would like to use it in my app.

One item, I am trying to resolve that has been deprecated in django 2.0, is rel.to.

[https://github.com/dulacp/django-accounting/blob/master/accounting/apps/books/mixins.py][1]

Line 44:

`field, m, direct, m2m = model._meta.get_field_by_name(source)` has now been replaced by `field = model._meta.get_field(source)`

Line 45:

```
rel = field.rel
    if not rel:
         # next field
         continue

    rel_model = rel.to
    try:
         rel_model._meta.get_field_by_name(self.relation_name)
```

has now been replaced by:

```
rel = field.remote_field
    if not rel:
         # next field
         continue

    remote_field = rel.to
    try:
         remote_field.model._meta.get_field_by_name(self.relation_name)
```

I have an error **ManyToOneRel' object has no attribute 'to'**. It will probably bring me to the next field to modify but if anybody got an idea how to resolve this, it could be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From older Django version [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.9.x/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py#L60)

> ```
> def to(self):
>     warnings.warn(
>         "Usage of ForeignObjectRel.to attribute has been deprecated. "
>         "Use the model attribute instead.",
>         RemovedInDjango20Warning, 2)
>     return self.model
> ```

so change

```
remote_field = rel.to
```

to

```
remote_field = rel.model
```

Comment: expected for project not being updated for 3 years :)